# Display list horizontally that is scrollable

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

This is my partial view

```
 @foreach (var user in Model)

{
    <ul class="menu">
        <li >

            @user.UserName

        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

This is my css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
  
}

  

      ul li::before {
            content: "\2022";
            color: forestgreen;
           
        }
    
    
    li {
       display:inline;
    }
```

This displays it vertically.I also did try overflow-x to no avail. Pls. point me to the right direction.

Comment: The white-space property will forbid a line break:  
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

Comment: @Amaury. Thank you but it still not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the foreach loop should be inside the `<ul>` element.

```
<ul class="menu">
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    <li >
        @user.UserName
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Claud30 if my reply is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks!